# Multiple Worksheet_change events firing each other

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a workbook with multiple Worksheet_Change events in the sheet.
Each of these macroes are related to an active x combobox.

The problem is that when I change one of the comboboxes the macro fires (as expected), which in turn start another macro (which is not suppose to run). I have already set the Application.EnableEvents = False
But the issue might be that I am changing a cell.value, which is linked to another combobox and hence also linked to another worksheet_change event.

A workaround as I see it, might be to only run the macro, if the combobox is the one actually selected, but here comes the second problem. I can't find a way to have vba return the name of the active combobox.

Please note that these comboboxes is not connected to a userform, they are simply placed directly on the worksheet.

Is there anybody who has any idea on how to solve this??

Any help is much appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

I see that there are 2 possible solutions...

1 - as stated by Gary's Student, you may have toggled the `Application.EnableEvents` somewhere unknowingly and you could try and trap where that happens.

2 - Maybe set a global boolean variable called, say `DontRunMacros` and set it to `TRUE` at the start of the first macro and to `FALSE` at the end. Then you simply have each other macro start with `If DontRunMacros Then Exit Sub` - That will prevent the others running regardless of the events that fire...

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could also set a global variable handling events. You check it at the beginning of each change event.

```
Dim ufEventsDisabled As Boolean

Sub YourSub()
    ufEventsDisabled = False
    Range("A1").Value=1 'This triggers the event

    ufEventsDisabled = True
    Range("A1").Value=1 'This doesn't trigger the event

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ufEventsDisabled=True Then Goto ExitEvent:
    'Your regular worksheet code

ExitEvent:
    ufEventsDisabled=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an error somewhere that is re-Enabling Events...........You can always insert:

```
MsgBox Application.EnableEvents
```

at points in your code to trap this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the quick responses.

I ended up using a named cell in the worksheet, similar to what hstay sugested.

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MD").Range("AllowMacro").Value = 0 Or Me.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then Exit Sub
```

However as I need the worksheet to calculate some cells while the code is running, I can't set application.Calculation = xlManual.
So the code still tries to execute a bunch of other change events, but the code above stops them from running more than just the first line. This however still takes a lot of time, which is quite frustrating. Guess I'll just need to take this in to account another time.

This is how I begin and end all my worksheet_chnage events:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MD").Range("AllowMacro").Value = 0 Or Me.Name <> 
ActiveSheet.Name Then Exit Sub
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MD").Range("AllowMacro").Value = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'some random code that trigger other change_events

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MD").Range("AllowMacro").Value = 1
```