# Not wanted autolooping macro in VBA (macro that loops 84-86 times spontaneously)

Tags: vba, excel

I have to make simple macro in VBA, which changes value of one cell, when I change this cell value form Excel. For example, I change in Excel value of cell to 100 and that triggers macro, which add to this cell value 1. I made it, but problem is quite weird... this macro triggers 84-86 times  i don't know why VBA is doing this to me, but i don't know how to handle with this problem.

Thanks for help!

Code of macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("D8")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        Cells(8, 4) = Cells(8, 4) + 1

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Guess what event is triggered when you change the contents of `Cells(8, 4)`.

Comment: Ah, I just again modify Range("D8"), so macro again is starting, right?

Comment: I'm not sure which one is a better duplicate for you, [Worksheet_change macro running multiple times in excel 2007](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32064447/11683), [Tables - Worksheet_Change Fires Multiple Times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41133592/11683) or [Multiple Worksheet_change events firing each other](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22692270/11683). Pick one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to make some order for you a bit.

Once you modify cell "D8" you enter inside `Worksheet_Change` event  and increment the value of cell "D8' by +1, this fires this code again, and so on, resulting in an endless loop. You can stop this by adding `Application.EnableEvents = False`, don't forget to restore it before exiting the `Sub`.

`Target` is defined `As Range`, so you don't need to use `Range(Target.Address)`, just use `Target`.

Once you entered the loop, you can replace `Cells(8, 4)` with `Target` since it's the same `Range` as checked previously in `Intersect(Target, Range("D8"))`.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D8")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = Target.Value + 1
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True '<-- restore setting

End Sub
```